# How to test a method that filters on several conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'd like to improve specs for a convenience method that returns an array of users whose purchases are due tomorrow and will be paid using a certain payment method (ignoring other payment methods).

The specs are something along the lines of:

```
it "doesn't return users without purchases being due tomorrow" do
  # create user and associated records that don't fit the time condition
  expect(subject).to eq([])
end

context "with users who have purchases due tomorrow" do

  it "returns users with $CERTAIN_PAYMENT_METHOD" do
    # create different users with different payment methods,
    # all matching the time condition.

    expect(subject).to eq([user_1, user_2])
  end


  it "doesn't return users without $CERTAIN_PAYMENT_METHOD" do
    # create user with credit card,
    # matching the time condition.

    expect(subject).to eq([])
  end

end
```

I see three possible approaches here:

1. Approach used above: Set up arbitrary combinations of records, and expect things specific to a single condition, always asserting the whole array. The setup can be long and repetitive.
2. Set up arbitrary combinations, and expect things to be included/excluded in the returned array. These "soft expectations" are great to read but can be very error-prone.
3. Set up (nearly) all combinations of records, and have a single expectation. This creates no overlap but also leaves developers in the dark as to *why* this method returns this specific array.

All approaches have their drawbacks, and I'm wondering if there's a best practice how to test methods like these?

Comment: Can you post your method under test too? At a first glance of your spec I would suggest that you break down your original method into smaller pieces and test them.

Answer (score 0):

Deciding between Option 1 and 2 can be tricky, but Option 3 is without a doubt the worst option. Unit Tests serve two purposes* - they drive clean code design and they document what the code does for the developers of the future. As you have correctly pointed out, having "one huge test" leaves developers in the dark as to why the method behaves as it does, and therefore destroys half of the benefit of the tests. Furthermore, these kinds of tests are not the sort of tests that drive out clean code design, so you are probably loosing that benefit too.

Whether Option 1 or 2 is better depends on your situation. Repetitive set up code is not necessarily a problem (research DAMP vs DRY with respect to TDD) and if it is a problem it could be improved by extracting common set up code so it can be shared between test cases (although this can be a smell if taken too far). In any case, I don't see how Option 2 solves the issue of repetitive set up code - the only difference between the two options is how you make the assertions.

The issue of "stock" vs "weak" assertions is a common theme (research strict mocks vs loose mocks) and is the main difference between Option 1 and 2. The problem with Option 1 is that making 1 change to production code can result in having to change the assertions for every single test case. For this reason I would advise having a couple of tests that assert on the whole array (to test ordering and completeness etc) but for most tests to be as specific as possible and only test include/excludes. This allows the test to clearly document which types of set ups result in which output values, rather than every test having a long list of assertions, only one of which is interesting to the current test case.

The guiding principal is, don't test the same thing twice. If, by asserting every element in every test, you feel like you are testing the same thing twice then it's probably not the right way to go.

* OK, sometimes they catch bugs too, but on their own they don't tell you that your system works and is bug free. That is the purpose of other forms of testing that test your entire system. Green unit tests do not give you enough confidence to release to production.

Comment: "Weak" assertions allow you to have a shared setup and use it selectively. If you add more users, the assertions won't fail because it will still "contain that specific user."

Comment: Selective set up is a bad idea as it hides what set up is relevant for which test. Any shared set up code should be essential set up for all the tests that use it. You should not add to the shared set up code to serve one additional test, because over time the purpose of each test becomes muddy. That's the beauty of repeating yourself in tests - each test remains easily readable and unchanged over time.